# Rails - ForeignKeyViolation in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, foreign-keys

How can I handle a `ForeignKeyViolation` error on form submit?

I have an input field expecting a `user_id` value; if I type an ID that does not exists, the form is still considered valid and it's submitted, but that error occurs, causing a server error.

How can I trigger a form error and add it to `f.object.errors` so I can inform the user to review the inserted ID in a nice&clean way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a validation to your model like this:

```
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
```

Comment: thanks, it works properly but it gives me a `User can't be blank` error. How can I provide a better error message (like "User ID is not valid") to handle this specific case?

Comment: Just add message as a pram. validates_presence_of :user, message: 'Your message'